# How can do this animate using WordPress / Jquery / css /HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Here is the video for reference. I have uploaded that into google drive. Please check this link and send me examples or code parts.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QcDMo0g7p9AoWfo4qzG0DGto_k2V4IIJ/view?usp=sharing

This animation needs to do it on mouse scroll or mouse hover.

Comment: I'm sorry, SO isn't an ab initio code-writing service. Please show us the code you have tried, describe what isn't working etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by html and css, first make those circles and set display:none for small circles, and then when you change state :hover, make transition .5s and display:block